# Will unmarking an answer as accepted remove a rep reward?

Tags: discussion, bounty, accepted-answer, etiquette

I received [an answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/57619/47914) to a question a long time ago. I've since come across a far better way to achieve what I was looking for, and would now like to share that information and mark it as the answer.

However, I noticed that the accepted answer was awarded 250 rep for answering the question. My concern is that if I unmark it, the user will lose the rep. Is this the case?

I know I should technically just give the question the best answer possible, but I feel bad about removing 250 rep from someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a better method then there is absolutely nothing wrong with posting an answer and accepting that instead, just as there would be nothing wrong with changing the accepted answer if you had a new and better answer from someone else. The accepted answer should be whichever answer you believe to be most useful; if that changes, change the mark.

As DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ said, the +250 is from a bounty and won't be affected by changing the accepted answer. Changing the accepted answer will take away the +15 originally awarded for accepting the answer. 15 rep is not a lot though and that shouldn't really affect your decision in which answer to accept and whether to change the accepted answer or not.

If you are going to change the accepted answer to a self answer then make sure your answer is actually adding something new though; if your answer is just restating or consolidating what has been said in other answers then I would consider posting an answer but leaving the accepted mark on whichever answer helped you the most.

Comment: Thank you. My answer is completely different, so I feel that I can post it with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

The 250 points were from a bounty awarded by someone else and doesn't effect the bounty receiver as the boutier would have been the one to reward it.

It's always great to leave an answer helping others with the information you learned but keep in mind that the indicated accepted answer you awarded in 2015 does come with a reward in the amount of 15 points.  Removing the accepted answer and awarding the accepted answer to yourself doesn't really benefit you.  Also, some sites and some members actually frown on that action as the sole reward is rep and if you read all the answers with not voting and not rewarding an answer that help you get your insight but make a compilation of all the answers to your own answer will lead to people not wanting to leave answers on your questions over time.

So to recap the 250 bounty you cannot effect.  Personally I would leave the accepted answer since you accepted it on a question from 2015 and I would just make another answer explaining what you learned.  If it's well written and detailed you could earn more rep for doing so.

Comment: It has nothing to do with any rep I would get from it. I found a far better way of achieving the effect I was after, which answers the question far better. Should I perhaps leave the answer marked but edit the OP, linking to my answer?

Comment: I wouldn't edit anything.  I would just leave a detailed answer explaining why your answer works best.

Comment: No one will see it if I do that. The answer will not help many people if it 1) doesn't have enough up-votes to get higher up, or 2) isn't marked as the answer, or 3) isn't mentioned specifically in the OP. I'm open to suggestions here, I'm just trying to make sure the answer reaches the viewers.

Comment: Any answers left on a question move that question to top of the site home page regardless of that questions age or if an answer has been already accepted.  That is the beauty of how the site works.

Comment: @ThomasMyron if somebody cant read all the aswers thay are a pillock anyway. Don't worry about the score, I certainly won't notice it in my tally.